# Como excluir commit de um branch no Git?

Tags: git, versionamento

Como eu posso excluir *commit* de um *branch*?

Eu fiz uma tentativa de tentar excluir um *commit* que não queria, porém acabei piorando mais a situação. Estou com medo de fazer algo errado.

O Git me diz pra eu usar `git reset --hard HEAD`, porém eu gostaria de confirmar antes de fazê-lo para que dê tudo certo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

É essencialmente quase isso mesmo se você quer excluir o *commit* atual. Provavelmente o que deseja é voltar para o *commit* anterior, então precisa pegar o atual - 1:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Se quer voltar para algum outro *commit* específico deve usar o *hash* dele. Ou em alguns casos pode fazer

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Tente com `--soft` antes e veja se resolve o que precisa. Ele é menos radical e mais seguro.

Se o *commit* já tinha sido enviado terá que forçar no remoto:

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Isto fará perder todas as alterações locais. Então se não pode perdê-las, sugiro fazer um *stash* com todas elas antes.

Se der errado pode reverter assim:

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

Se está com medo de fazer algo errado, faça um *backup* antes e pode voltar ao original se não sair como esperava (em geral isso não deveria ser necessário porque o objetivo dessa ferramenta é justamente este, mas sabemos como é...).

Se quiser fazer no remoto:

```
git push origin +HEAD^:master #ou outro nome aqui
```

Se o medo se estende ao servidor remoto, faça  o mesmo com ele. Se envolver o servidor remoto, vários cuidados precisam ser tomados, o principal é que seu *branch* atual deve ser o mais novo do remoto. Se isto não for garantido, estará criando uma realidade alternativa para os demais usuários.

[Leitura recomendável](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

A exclusão permanente de um (1) commit pode ser feito pelo comando abaixo:

```
 git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Você pode substituir o `1` pelo número de commits que deseja remover.

Se este *commit* removido está **também** na branch remota (GitHub, Gitlab, etc), você precisa aplicar o comando *force* (`-f`) para fazer o `push` para a branch remota:

```
git push -f
```

Contudo, **eu não recomendo** aplicar qualquer comando com as opções `-f` ou `--hard` se:

- Existem novos commits após este commit que deseja remover.
- Existem novas branchs criadas a partir deste commit removido desta mesma branch.

Neste casos, tente primeiro usar o `git revert`.