# Como apagar commits do gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

É possível apagar commits do gitlab usando comandos git?

Já tentei atraves do visual studio da opção > Team Explorer mas sem sucesso

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170531/64969

Comment: Relacionado, talvez até duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128578/64969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar reescrever o seu histórico com `git reset` e, então, dar um `git push --force`.

Eu prefiro fazer o `reset` a partir do `gitk`:

[image: Usando o <code>gitk</code> para fazer o <code>git reset</code>]

Assim, você consegue fazer o `reset` para qualquer ponto em seu histórico. Para propagar isso, você deve fazer o chamado *force push*, em que você força uma atualização do *branch* remoto. Ocasionalmente, quando o coletor de lixo fo GitLab vier, seus *commits* antigos realmente devem ser apagados.

> **NOTA**: se alguém fez o *fork* do seu projeto antes de você resetar esses valores, então é bem capaz de que esses *commits* perdurem. Então, se você tem informação sigilosa, atue o mais rápido possível.

Caso você só deseja eliminar um único *commit* da lista, é possível pegar os demais *commits* depois do `git reset` fazendo o `git cherry-pick`.

No meu caso, se eu desejasse remover o *commit* de mensagem "**Tabulação onde ela é devida**", deveria fazer ainda 4 cherry-picks:

```
git cherry-pick 11de53691964
git cherry-pick f119d69fe118
git cherry-pick f119d69fe118
git cherry-pick 9065a4213bd5
```

Eu já precisei usar dessa estratégia para apagar dados que subi erroneamente para o GitHub, felizmente não percebi nenhuma leitura no projeto antes do ajuste. Em outras circunstâncias, já precisei desfazer **merge requests** no GitLab. Diversas vezes.

Fazer o `revert` não me foi o adequado na maioria das vezes, pois depois causa confusão no histórico com o código antigo (se ele deveria realmente entrar). O `revert`, para mim, se adequou quando o código antigo preciso ser totalmente desfeito sem maiores danos e ele já estava propagado demais para simplesmente ser apagado via `git reset` + *force push*.

Uma situação *o'concur* em que usei o `revert` com sucesso foi no *commit* de *merge*, para então criar um novo *merge request* com o `revert` do `revert`. Isso serviu para remover um código ligeiramente defeituoso que entrou e, também, serviu de base para escrever comentários de revisão no código.

---

Se você não tiver acesso a linha de comando ou simplesmente a abolir, tem a opção via Web-GUI.

Vou pegar o seguinte exemplo: tenho um branch `master` com os seguintes commits (ordem do histórico):

1. A (2fc99739)
2. B (5a0015bc)
3. C (75092a6b)

Eu quero reescrever da seguinte forma:

1. A (2fc99739)
2. C (???)

Removendo o B do histórico.

No meu repositório, já criei um branch chamado `fail-safe` para eventuais catástrofes.

Primeiro, devemos criar um branch novo a no commit A:

[image: criando novo branch]

Então, catamos o commit desejado do branch antigo (`master` no caso):

[image: abrindo o histórico e catando o commit]

Após isso, selecionamos os commits desejado para cherry-pick `75092a6b`. Eu abri em outra aba, recomendo abrir todos os commit desejáveis de cherry-pick em outras abas (ordem cronológica) e selecionamos a opção `cherry-pick` e pomos como alvo `salvador-patria`:

[image: fazendo cherry-pick]

Pois bem, agora temos um branch com o histórico correto: `salvador-patria`. Precisamos apenas excluir o `master` anterior e substitui-lo com o histórico de `salvador-patria`.

Para isso, precisamos remover o default do `master` primeiro (fiz isso atribuindo para outro branch qualquer):

[image: removendo o default e apagando o branch]

Então, agora basta criar um novo branch a partir de `salvador-patria` chamado `master` e colocá-lo como default novamente. Esses dois processos já foram mostrados anteriormente, então não tem porque fazer novos gifs.

Answer (score 5):

Tente reverter seu commit no gitlab:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referencias:

1. [Gitlab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/revert_changes.html)

Caso não seja isso que você procure, você pode dar uma olhada nessa documentação no [Gitlab - Rollback Commits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/university/training/topics/rollback_commits.html)

Comment: Reverter não é apagar =/