# Como excluir commits do git e passar a considerar o antigo com novas implementações?

Tags: git, gitlab

Pessoal tenho o seguinte problema, estava desenvolvendo e comitando aos poucos as alterações, quando cheguei em um certo ponto tive que voltar em um dos commits usando:

```
 git reset --hard <numero do commit>
```

Pois vi que depois dele uma funcionalidade parava de funcionar.

Só que eu acabei deixando nesse commit que voltei e implementei mais coisas. Quando fui fazer o `push`, obviamente deu pau rs. Pediu pra eu fazer o `pull`, só que não quero dar `pull` dos commits depois desse, quero apenas subir o commit que eu voltei com as novas implementações que fiz em cima dele.

Alguém sabe como contorno isso sem perder os dados que implementei no commit antigo? Quero poder descartar os commits que estão a frente dele, e considerar apenas esse commit com as coisas novas que commitei por último.

Comment: pode usar o comando push com a flag --force. Essa flag sobrescreve o conteúdo mesmo se o remote estiver a frente. Antes de executar, dê uma lida na documentação, ver se é realmente isso: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: @Pedro não recomendo. Melhor seria fazer um branch a partir do ponto desejado e "colher cereja" das mudanças desejadas

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, concordo, o push --force é um tanto quanto perigoso, e o cherry pick em uma branch separada seria o melhor caminho. Porém, recomendei esse método pela frase   "Quero poder descartar os commits que estão a frente dele....", o que não é possível fazer com o cherry / merge

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado mas depois que voltei a branch x, eu commitei outras coisas em cima. Vou perdê-las também?

Comment: @GabrielaMendonça você tem o gitk instalado na máquina? Se sim, você pode mostrar a sua árvore de commits, poderia subir a árvore de commits na pergunta? Eu não entendi o que você disse no comentário, fiquei perdido

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado coloquei na resposta aí a imagem

Comment: @GabrielaMendonça moça , você deveria dar um [edit] na questão , não por uma resposta. O que você pôs não é uma resposta, deveria ser apenas uma edição da questão

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado beleza jovem, dá próxima edito. valeu! Eu já resolvi aqui com o force mesmo. Obrigada!!

Comment: Seu problema lembra este daqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271209/64969; se for, pode marcar como duplicada?